# RenderScript Text Size

Tags: android, renderscript

How do I set the font characteristics before calling rsgDrawText?  I'm specifically interested in being able to set the font size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a multi-part process. In the file you use to control the RenderScript runtime (the one which owns the script usually) do the following after initializing the script but before binding it:

```
 Font mFontSans; //This can be a class member variable.

 private void initFonts() {
      // Sans font by family name
      mFontSans = Font.create(mRS, mRes, "sans-serif", Font.Style.NORMAL, 8);
      mScript.set_gFontSans(mFontSans);
 }
```

Then in the RenderScript file have a global variable (in this case gFontSans) and call:

```
 rsgBindFont(gFontSans);
```

Sometime before you draw the text you want. If you need different sizes you need to have them stored as separate variables, or an array.

Comment: If you need additional reference, I sample code rsRenderStates included with the samples has a pretty good section dedicated solely to handling fonts.